# Use source files generated by ANTLR

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, antlr, antlr4

I use ANTLR with the maven plugin to generate the source files. When creating them with `mvn package` they get correctly compiled and put together into `target/generated-sources/antlr4`, but from there I cannot access them in from my project.

My question is if I should be able to do this and import them somehow or if I need to move them from there to `src`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:
My `pom.xml` was missing `<phase>generate-sources</phase>` which was not mentioned in the [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-antlr) I was following. After adding this to the `execution` tag it all worked and I could use it in my project!